# Cordova Plugin js-module Limitation

Tags: javascript, cordova

So I'm creating a Cordova plugin that needs to pull in a whole bunch of js files, 5 in total, each one of them needs to execute code.  I understand that if I declare it like this,

---

//in Plugin.xml

```
<js-module src="www/js/alice.js" name="alice">
    <runs/>
</js-module>
<js-module src="www/js/bob.js" name="bob">
    <runs/>
</js-module>
```

The should both run, and considering the following code,

//in alice.js

```
function alice()
{
    console.log("Hello World From Alice!");
}
```

//in bob.js

```
function bob()
{
    console.log("Hello World From Bob! Are you there Alice?");
    alice();
}

bob();
```

---

//Output

```
Hello World From Bob! Are you there Alice?
Uncaught ReferenceError: alice is not defined
```

---

Now bob executes fine, but it can't find the alice method even though that script executes prior to bob.  Any idea how to get around this issue, if it's even possible to do so?  Merging all my js into a single file is not an option unfortunately.

---

Edit: (16:00) 28/05/2015

Okay so I have another idea of including one script with the "runs" attribute, and just copying the remaining scripts without the attribute.  This script will then embed the copied scripts for me, execute then go onto the next in a kind of linked list.  My init script looks like this,

```
var scripts = [
    "js/1.js",
    "js/2.js",
    "js/3.js",
    "js/4.js",
    "js/startup.js"
]

function InjectLinkedScript(parent, scripts, index)
{
    console.log("Injecting script '" + scripts[index] + "', at index '" + index + "'.");
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = scripts[index];
    script.onload = function(script)
    {
        if(index < (scripts.length - 1))
        {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
            InjectLinkedScript(head, scripts, index + 1);   
        }
    };
    head.appendChild(script);
}

var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
InjectLinkedScript(head, scripts, 0);
```

The final script, has some code that I would like to execute that completes my initialisation, unfortunately it then embeds all of the scripts again but I don't know why.  My plugin.xml looks like this,

```
<asset src="www/js" target="js" />
<js-module src="www/jspre/init.js" name="init">
    <runs/>
</js-module>
```

The asset tag, are my scripts that i just want to copy over, and the js-module one is the script above that executes the second its injected.

So just to recap what happens here, init.js injects 1.js into the header, which then executes, once 1.js then injects 2.js, and so on until 4.js injects startup.js which has my method that I would like to call.  I can let the script finish and exit at that point and then use the JavaScript console to execute the method in startup.js myself, this results in a bunch of scripts being embedded again.  But they are already there and ready, I don't need them embedded again.

Comment: You need to import Alice or add alice to the `cordova.plugins` namespace, either with a module.exports or actually assigning the alice object.

Comment: If you look at the ngCordova project on github and some of the projects it creates wrappers for, you'll find they do this.

Comment: so from what I've just looked at, I have to use angular for my project to be able to do this?  It seems massively over complicated and not suitable to be honest, I'm making a plugin, I don't think it's correct to force Angular on the app using my plugin, I just need the scripts to execute in sequence and be put into the index.html page automatically.  It seems the issue here is script injection that behaves differently from scripts included normally.

Comment: no, you don't have to use angular; I was having you look at the source so you can see how the plugins are called. You can also look at any cordova plugin and see how they create themselves.

Comment: Hi George, that's what I've been using as examples, existing projects.  None that I have found so far have included the kind of scripts I require so it hasn't been easy to work out.

Comment: Okay so I've been trying another method that very *almost* works, except I get some odd behavior at the last moment,  what I do is I have all the scripts that I want to copy without the "runs" attribute in one folder, and an init.js script in another folder that gets included with the "runs" attribute.  That script then dynamically injects each of my scripts in sequence, in a kind of linked list, once one completes the next gets injected.  This works except at the end I need to call one of the methods from scripts that were included, it then injects the scripts again.

Comment: I'll include my new init script above.

Comment: Actually, it seems to work like this, I think I have something else causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<runs/>` node causes the defined `<js-module>` to be made available on the plugin's namespace. This means to use a defined module you need to `require()` it with the prefix of your plugins id followed by the `name` of your js-module.

You also need to need to use `exports` to gain access to your components methods.

So to get your bob snippet to work your code would be as follows.

**plugin.xml**

```
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-bob-and-alice" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <js-module src="www/js/alice.js" name="alice">
        <runs/>
    </js-module>
    <js-module src="www/js/bob.js" name="bob">
         <runs/>
    </js-module>
</plugin>
```

**alice.js**

```
function alice(){
   console.log("Hello World From Alice!");
}
module.exports = alice;
```

**bob.js**

```
var alice = require('cordova-plugin-bob-and-alice.alice');

function bob(){
    console.log("Hello World From Bob! Are you there Alice?");
    alice();
}

bob();

module.exports = bob;
```

The `bob()` method will execute because you have executed it at run time. If you wanted to implement it as a reusable method you would need to export it from the js file as well.

Also I can't see any reason technically or otherwise as to why you couldn't have more than one `<runs/>` module. The intend is to create reusable modules between plugins. You can even import `<js-modules/>` that have been defined by other plugins.

**Also..**

As a last note you can make your plugin available in the DOM by using either the `<clobbers/>` or `<merges/>` instead of run.

For example :

**plugin.xml**

```
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-bob-and-alice" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <js-module src="www/js/alice.js" name="alice">
        <clobbers target="alice"/>
    </js-module>
    <js-module src="www/js/bob.js" name="bob">
         <merges target="cordova.plugins"/>
    </js-module>
</plugin>
```

In which case you would be able to call both elements within your webview.

```
alice();
cordova.plugins.bob();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have up to one "runs" tag

Official documentation:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md

Comment: okay, so would setting only one as Run get the behavior that I need here?  I've tried just bob.js, but it still can't find the alice method.

Comment: no, as far as i know you cannot do that with this method. You either reorganize your js files in order to load in one, or you need to try some other method to do this. as "George Stocker" mentioned above, you have some examples in the ngCordovaproject